# How can I modify the android keyboard in ionic app

Tags: android, keyboard, ionic-framework, mobile-development

Basically what I want is the addition of few buttons such as '@outlook.com', '@gmail.com', '@yahoo.com', etc in the android keyboard how can I acheive this in Ionic or if there is any other way let me know.

[image: modified keyboard in android]

Comment: You can not modify keyboard in any platform.